# Pass WordPress user email to calendly widget

Tags: wordpress, calendly

I would like to pass my logged in WP user email and user first/last names to my calendly widget. The calendly documentation explains how to do so with parameters but I'd like to do it without parameters, directly taking those from WP.

I haven't been able to find the solution and lack PHP skills.

This is what I have:

```
    <!-- Calendly inline widget begin -->
    <div class="calendly-inline-widget" style="min-width:320px;height:580px;" data-auto- load="false">
    <script type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js"></script>
    <script>
    Calendly.initInlineWidget({
    url: 'https://calendly.com/fabiennewintle/chat',
    prefill: {
       name: first_name,
       email: user_email,
     }
   });
    </script>
   </div>
   <!-- Calendly inline widget end -->
```

The problem is with the prefill, I imagine I would have to use the wp_get_current_user() { function but I don't know how to use it and how to connect it to this iframe from my child functions.php.

If anyone had any advice I'd very much appreciate it.